# Wordpress Mobile Menu Not Appearing

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu, responsive-design

I've installed a new theme on a Wordpress website and I'm struggling to get the mobile menu to appear above the content.

I've tried changing the z-index value for #mobile-menu but it still seems to be sitting behind the slider.

You can see the issue here: http://www.thisblondemind.co.uk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line of your `style.css` line 2017

```
@media screen and (max-width: 568px)
.menu-mobile, .menu-mobile ul, .menu-mobile li, .menu-mobile a {
    margin: 0;
    paddding: 0;
}
```

To this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 568px)
.menu-mobile, .menu-mobile ul, .menu-mobile li, .menu-mobile a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
    margin: 0;
    paddding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should give the actual menu these properties:

```
#menu-menu-1 {
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
}
```

see this screen capture with applied properties:

[image: with properties]